# How to add periods efficiently

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a timestamp `t` and I would like to find out the timestamp `t'` that is at the beginning of the next Period `p` after the period that `t` is in, starting from the year 0.

Example:

```
t = 2014-10-24T11:10:23.456Z
p = P1D

t' would be 2014-10-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

Please note, that p could be any ISO 8601 period.

My current implementation that works (but is extremely slow!):

```
Period p = Period.parse("P1M1D");

final MutableDateTime start= new MutableDateTime(startTimestamp);
final MutableDateTime currentEnd = new MutableDateTime(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);

while (currentEnd.compareTo(start) <= 0) {
    currentEnd.add(p);
}
System.out.println(currentEnd);

--> 2014-11-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

Can you think of a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The low performance is not surprising if you start your loop with year zero! Why do you need this exotic start condition (currentEnd-year starting with 0)?

Comment: because I can have periods "P1M1D". So there are a number of periods since the beginning of time and I don't know when the "current" one starts and finishes.

Comment: And why is year 0 the "beginning of time" for you? Why not even one billion years ago or your birth date? This seems to be an arbitrary definition. In this context of an uncertain start time, it is not clear at all what the result means. What do you finally want to do with your result? Use-case?

Comment: Reading again your sentence "...after the period that `t` is in...", I think you misunderstand the concept of a period in Joda-Time. This type does not have any anchor on the timeline, hence is not fixed to any date but only denotes a temporal amount respective a length in time. So a given point in time `t` can never be "in a period", but only inside an interval.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i will look into this again

Comment: Also note that a period of 1D may shift by some seconds due to time changes over hundreds of years. Probably better to do some custom processing here with `.withStartOfDay()` type logic.